# show that ln is the reverse function of exp

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

my problem:

For $z \in \Omega:=\mathbb{C} \backslash(-\infty, 0]$ let the main value Arg $z$ of the argument of $z$ be $−\pi < \operatorname{Arg} z < \pi$. (argument $\varphi$ of $z$ ist modulo 2$\pi$  defined as $z=|z| e^{i \varphi}$.) the main branch of the logarithm is given as:

$\operatorname{Ln} z:=\ln |z|+i \cdot \operatorname{Arg} z$

show:
(a)Ln is the reverse function of $\exp :\{z \in \mathbb{C} ;-\pi<\operatorname{Im} z<\pi\} \rightarrow \Omega$.
(b) Ln is holomorph and $\operatorname{Ln}^{\prime}(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ .

My idea: maybe in (a) i have to start with the lnz definition and then try to get to the exp function? how to use the other informations?

Comment: For (a): Have you tried just plugging one into the other? So consider $\mathrm{Ln}(\exp z) = \ln(|\exp z|) + i \mathrm{Arg}(\exp z)$ where $z=a+ib$ for real a,b.